# What is {nk} in loopback API explorer?

Tags: loopbackjs

[image: Screenshot of loopback API explorer]

I'm using loopback3.x. Some of the REST APIs contains {nk}. The description of {nk} is given as "Foreign key for interviews". What is {nk} refers to? What is the difference between {nk} and {fk}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's related to [Nested queries](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Nested-queries.html).

May be {nk} stands for nested foreign key.